# Rails + Postgres: How to `order` Using Multiple Possibly Nil Columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, arel

I have a table in a Rails application which stores two attributes, one of which is a timestamp (`sent_at`, as in `Time.now`), and the other a date (`sent_on`, as in `Time.now.to_date`).

I'd like to retrieve rows in ascending order by their `sent_at`|`sent_on` (either one of those could be `nil`):

```rb
Order.first(20).order(sent_at: :asc, sent_on: :asc) # this doesn't work
```

How would you go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about rails, but in SQL I would try ```COALESCE(sent_at, sent_on) ASC```. Perhaps you can ttranslate this

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is wrong with the current output and what did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've taken the liberty to use the [comment of Islingre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914268/rails-postgres-how-to-order-using-multiple-possibly-nil-columns#comment102248697_57914268). You can use [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to evaluate it's arguments in order. The first argument that is not `NULL` will be returned.

```
named_function = ::Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction
orders = Order.arel_table
Order.order(named_function.new('COALESCE', [orders[:sent_at], orders[:send_on]]).asc).first(20)

# results in:
#
# SELECT "orders".*
# FROM "orders"
# ORDER BY COALESCE("orders"."send_at", "orders"."send_on") ASC
# LIMIT 20
```

Or if you don't mind the use of plain SQL.

```
Order.order('COALESCE(sent_at, sent_on) ASC').first(20)

# results in:
#
# SELECT "orders".*
# FROM "orders"
# ORDER BY COALESCE(sent_at, sent_on) ASC
# LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)